# Is There A Way To Simply Use All Nexus Repositories?

Tags: maven-3, nexus, sonatype, maven-repository, maven-mirroring

#### What are the details of your problem?

I have a [Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository) that has an unknown number of hosted repositories for the [Maven-3 m2](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) format. I'd like to easily make sure all available options are being used from this Nexus. I can see many options being listed available on the Nexus search but at maven build are not being found.

1. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo.1
2. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo.2
3. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo.A
4. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo.N
5. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo.A2

#### What did you try and what were you expecting?

I was expecting that if I gave the overarching Sonatype Nexus URL e.g. Sonatype.Nexus.Repo that that'd be fine enough for redirects to figure out and auto-manage. But actually, none of the artifacts seemed to resolve.

I don't know if I just haven't been searching the right key terms or my phrasing has been wonky. Is there a way to force Maven to use all the sub-repositories of the main Nexus? Is there a Nexus URL format that will automatically provide all the available repositories' Maven packages in one link? Is there a way to have Maven check every mirror listed for `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>`?

Comment: define a group in Nexus and add those repos to that group... and use the group repository as entry in your settings.xml ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't have permissions

Comment: So someone else to do that for you ...Haven't you provided with a full setup for your environment?